# Packaging custom properties for mysites in sharepoint 2010

Tags: my-site, properties

Is it possible to package custom properties that i manually create for profile for mysites in sharepoint 2010. E.G. music, hobbies ...

So next time i just next time i dont need to do it manually when im putting mysite on the production. So i just execute some wsp to create them all etc.

If it is possible, then how do i do that.

Any usefull links or info would be appreciented.

Thanks in advance

PS: extra information to clarify things:

What are properties im talking about:
I created a mysite host, and i have my profile the profile has standard properties like skills, interests, name, etc etc. For my solution i needed extra properties like hobby, sport, music etc ...

So what i did i went to user profiles in administration central and i manually added those properties to user profile, now when you open the profiles i see those properties.

So to avoid that extra manual work i want to make sure those 3 extra properties are created automatically. So i dont go to do it all over again on production server, but instead i deploy a package and the properties are there ... but the question is how do i do that and is it possible?

Links or extra infor is appreciated

Comment: I don't understand completely what properties you talking about.
May be you are searching for feature stampling. It give you ability to execute some code in event of my site creation and you can set some properties by this code.

Comment: I updated the post with extra info!

Answer (score 1):

Now it has become clear =)

[MSDN: How to: Create and Edit a User Profile Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms519896%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Use this code with some your feature activated event.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be a repeatable proces, script it:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/create-user-profile-properties-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/